# Best aproach for commenting source code to understand the workflow of the whole project?

Tags: java, project-management, comments, project

in private and in companies it is over and over again a problem that I or we developers comment in fact our code but generally nobody knows exactly how the code of the whole project works together. When I write my own code and the project is getting bigger I sometimes have this problem too. Although I write tons of comments, after 3 months you don't know what the whole thing exactly does, that means how the different methods and classes work together.
How do you solve this in your company or in private (if there is just marginal project development and no requirements specification). Or do you have always such a good project development with contract document and requirements specification that you don't have to worry about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Code complete](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1310718047&sr=8-1) can explain the solution to your problem better than I ever could.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The book has got very good ratings.

Comment: Its the best programming book I have ever read, I really recomend it.

Answer (score 3):

I find the best way to solve this is to write a functional test using a unit test framework.

In a functional test you write a test which loads up several if not all the core components laid bare.  This shows that all the components work correctly together but also you get a documents which shows you in one place how everything connects.

Depending on how complex you interactions are, you may not be enough and you need to document it.  Personally I would prefer to make the code simple so that documenting it is not really needed or is relatively easy to explain.

If documenting it sounds too hard, its time to refactor your code so that its not.

Comment: You should have such a test for every business requirement anyway ...

Answer (score 1):

Take your time a create some short and simple design documents, add some UML diagrams to just show the basic ideas behind the whole application. This would give new team players a quick overview. Publish this documentation on an internal wiki and encourage the team to enhance, if necessary.

Then, as Peter suggested, some well documented test cases really help: Read the test code and learn how to use the API. (and, as a *secondary* effect, test the code ;-) )

I would not put too much effort on comments, especially on line comments. The tend to become out dated, because no unit test verifies that line comments are still valid and, even worth, no one ever deletes unnecessary comments.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Part of what you are asking relates to code maintainability. In my view the two main things you can do to improve this are:-

- Write some design documentation
- Develop maintainable and clearly written code

From past experience the first item is very often neglected on software projects due to time constraints, but I think that if you can produce at least a class diagram of your system, then this is worth a lot in terms of understanding how objects interract when you revisit the code in a few months. Depending on the complexity, then sequence diagrams can also be useful. Producing this documentation will also be of benefit to new members of the team, in quickly having an overview of how the software is structured.

I can't stress enough the importance of writing clear and maintainable code. My eyes were recently opened when I read [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1310719004&sr=8-1) by Robert Martin. You owe it to yourself and your fellow developers to read at least the first couple of chapters in this book. That alone will immediately improve the readability and maintainability of your code.

The idea is that the code should read almost like a narrative, where methods follow in a logical order, are short, appropriately named, and take few parameters. Doing this almost eliminates the need for code comments, and improves the code structure.